# How do I list my google events in a list using electron

Tags: html, node.js, variables, electron

I am working on a simple electron app that displays my google agenda - for this i use the node.js quickstart guide from google and tried to make a gui with electron/HTML. Now i get my data. I can write it in my console using this function:

```
async function listEvents(auth, win) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  const res = await calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  });
  const events = res.data.items;
  if (!events || events.length === 0) {
    console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
  events.map((event, i) => {
    const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
    console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
  });

  
}
```

And then I store it in a array (i think) using this:

```
win.webContents.send('events', events);
```

Next in my main.js i got this:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const { listEvents } = require('./index.js')
const { authorize } = require('./index.js')

let win

async function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')

  // Call the listEvents function from index.js
  const auth = await authorize();
  const events = await listEvents(auth, win);

  // Send the events to the renderer process
  win.webContents.send('events', events);
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

and then i try to display it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GUI</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Google Calendar API GUI</h1>
    <ul id="events"></ul>

    <script>
      const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
      // Listen for the 'events' message from the main process
    ipcRenderer.on('events', (event, events) => {
    const eventsList = document.getElementById('events');
    eventsList.innerHTML = '';

    for (const event of events) {
      const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.textContent = `${start} - ${event.summary}`;
      eventsList.appendChild(li);
    }
})
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So now what do i do? am i missing something, ive tried a couple things: renaming my window, editing variable names becouse i thought that i might have used some that i had arleady used somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the `events` from your `listEvents` function

```
async function listEvents(auth, win) {
  ...
  const events = res.data.items;
  ...
  return events;
}
```

and don't need to change the rest of your code.

at `createWindow` you'll obtain the `events` and send them to the renderer.

```
  const events = await listEvents(auth, win);
  win.webContents.send('events', events);
```

and you will display them in your gui

```
  ipcRenderer.on('events', (e, events) => {
    ...
    for (const event of events) {
      ...
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.textContent = `${start} - ${event.summary}`;
      eventsList.appendChild(li);
    }
```